# What is the easiest way to create a copy of an AWS SQL RDS from one account to another?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot

I want to migrate a RDS database that is located on AWS account "A" to AWS account "B", but i want to have my own copy of the RDS database on account "B".

I want to make sure what is the easiest way and to have an independent copy on account "B"

Comment: what flavor of rds? i.e. sql server?

Comment: SQL  @E.J.Brennan

Comment: SQL is a language. EJ Brennan was asking what DBMS engine you're using: MySQL, Postgres, MariaDB, Oracle, or SQL Server?

Comment: Also, when you say "migrate" does that mean that you're going to be moving the database for a live application? If yes, how much downtime can you tolerate? If no, is there any requirement that the destination database remain synchronized to the source database?

Comment: I'm working with a new client which has a grumpy development team, i'm guessing this DB is MySQL or SQL Server, no downtime required, they are going to switch DB off, new database does not need to stay synchronized to the source DB.

Comment: This really isn't the place to be guessing, especially if you have a zero-downtime requirement. I suggest that you learn exactly what database server they're using, read the documentation for that server to understand zero-downtime migrations, and then try it out in your own account before you damage their database. Or tell them that you're not the right person to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is going to be to take a manual snapshot on the account on the account currently hosting the RDS database.

Once the snapshot is complete you can then share this with the other account.

The other account can then launch a new RDS instance from this snapshot. Once this instance has been launched the snapshot can be removed. Be aware if they are in a different region you will also need to [copy the snapshot to the destination region](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-region-snapshot-copy-for-amazon-rds/) before you share with the other account.

Some links that may be of use to you:

- [How do I share manual Amazon RDS DB snapshots or Aurora DB cluster snapshots with another AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-snapshots-share-account/)
- [Restore a DB Instance from a DB Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.RestoringFromSnapshot.html)